# Generalized Problem of Hanoi Towers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Let's consider the well known problem of "Hanoi Towers", but in a more generalized version (i.e $n$ rods, $m$ disks). Also, we consider each state of the problem as the following :

$[n,r_1,r_2,...,r_m]$ which means that on the first position we have the number of rods (i.e. $n$), and then each disk's rod ($r_i$ means that the $i$-th disk is placed on $r_i$ rod, $r_i$ $\in$ $\{1,2,...,n\}$, $i = \overline{1,m}$)

For example, the initial state is $[n,1,1,...,1]$, $1$ is repeated $m$ times (all the disks are on the first rod at begining). Also, the final state will be $[n,n,n,...,n]$.

Having established this part, we can imagine a graph where each node is one of the states defined above where each transition is according to the hanoi towers rule (a smaller disk will be placed on a larger disk from another rod).

Formally, we define it in the following way:

$[n,...,r_i,...,r_j,...]$  $=>$ $[n,...,r_j,...,r_j,...]$ if we move the disk from $i$-th rod to the $j$-th. Another important thing to see is if in such state there exist repeating values (i.e after we make a transition), the smaller disk ($i$-th one in our case) will be on the left side of the larger one ($j$-th).

It's clear that we can create this graph using this tehnique (it can have exponential number of nodes). Anyway, I am interested in the following problem.

Having the states and the transitions defined as above, what would be the best heuristic function (the $h$ function) in $A^*$ ($A$ star) algorithm to implement, in order to achieve the optimal solution ?

The pseudo-code of $A^*$ algorithm can be seen here : http://mat.uab.cat/~alseda/MasterOpt/AStar-Algorithm.pdf

Clear that this will be an exponential algorithm (with respect to the used memory), but I want to implement this for pretty small numbers $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Why don't you just find the shortest path in your graph?

Comment: @wece, Yes finally I solved it in that way, But  I still want to know what heuristic function would fit in this case

Comment: The heuristic "shortest path" would give you the solution.